# How to load css file in JavaFX 2?

Tags: css, javafx-2

Wrote my JavaFX classes in `com.xyz.abc package (ex: com.xyz.abc.Sample.java)`
and wrote my CSS files in `root/css/styles.css.

How do I load this CSS file into `Sample.java`?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your scene at the begining of your app

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/to/your/stylesheet.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for how paths are resolved:

> A style sheet URL may be an absolute URL or a relative URL. If a
>   relative URL is given, it is resolved against the base URL of the
>   ClassLoader of the concrete Application class. If, for example, there
>   is a main class com.wicked.cool.ui.Main that extends Application, the
>   relative URL "com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css" would resolve
>   correctly. The relative URL "../resources/styles.css" would not since
>   the path ".." relative to the root is not a valid path. It is often
>   easier to use the ClassLoader of some class to find the resource. For
>   example, if the "styles.css" file resides in the same package as Main,
>   the following code will give the correct URL:
>   com.wicked.cool.ui.Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm()
>
> Note that, beginning with JavaFX 2.1, a URL consisting of only an
>   absolute path (having no scheme or authority) is resolved relative to
>   the base URL of ClassLoader of the class that extends Application. In
>   other words, "/com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css" is treated as
>   "com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css". This is consistent with FXML.

So your question isn't quite clear, but if "root" is the classpath of your application, you probably want

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

If "root" is actually a directory in the classpath, then replace "css/styles.css" with "root/css/styles.css".